# An integral over $SU(N)$.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

A physics textbook I am reading uses the following inequality:
$$ \int_{SU(N)} d \gamma \overline{\chi_r(\gamma)} \left( \chi_f(\gamma) \right)^m \left( \overline{\chi_f(\gamma)} \right)^n \geq 0$$
where $\chi_r$ is the character for some irreducible representation, 
$\chi_f$ is the character of the $N$ dimensional/fundamental representation of $SU(N)$, 
and $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers, and $d \gamma$ is the Haar-measure.
How can I establish this inequality?

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: Any integral of products of characters is a nonnegative integer, because it’s the dimension of a space of invariants.